# Шрифты в Mozila не грузятся

Tags: шрифты

Проблема состоит в том, что страницы в папке HTML, стили в папке CSS, шрифты в WEBFONTS. Все шрифты конвертированы, все пути прописаны. Во всех браузерах шрифты подключаются, в мозиле - нет. Примечательно то, что если страницы в корне (а не в папке HTML), то шрифты подгружаются в мозиле.
В чем проблема, что за особенность такая?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'open_sanscondensed_light';
    src: url('../webfonts/opensans-condlight-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../webfonts/opensans-condlight-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../webfonts/opensans-condlight-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../webfonts/opensans-condlight-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../webfonts/opensans-condlight-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../webfonts/opensans-condlight-webfont.svg#open_sanscondensed_light') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Проверьте настройки Adblock если он установлен.

Comment: <br> - нужно убрать

Comment: @sashatexb, это глюк редактирования.